# Non-binary 1-error correcting code

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm stuck with this question:

Find an 1-error-correcting code in $\mathbf{Z}_{5}^{6} = \mathbf{Z_5}\, \times \, \mathbf{Z_5}\, \times \, \mathbf{Z_5}\, \times \, \mathbf{Z_5}\, \times \, \mathbf{Z_5}\, \times \, \mathbf{Z_5}$ with as many words as possible.

I know there is a good formula for binary codes that correct up to $e$ errors, i.e., $2^{n-k} \geq 1$ + $n \choose 1$ + $ \ldots$ + $n \choose e$, where $n$ is the length of the code and $k$ the dimension. But I don't know how to solve this in mod 5.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/607043/15941).  My comment (a hint) on the other question can be used to find the answer to this homework-type question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A $t$-error correcting code has minimal distance $d=2t+1$, so we have to compute $A_q(n,d)$ for $q=5$, $n=6$ and $d=3$. Appyling Singleton's bound, or sphere packing bound we see that $A_q(n,d)\le 5^4$. So is there such a code with $5^4$ words ? What about linear codes ?
If it has $5^4$ words, it is a perfect code. Follow the hint of Dilip.